# Accidentally shorted my Pi

Tags: gpio, pi-3, rip

I made a little "montage" where I could control LEDs with my Pi and accidentally shorted the 5 V with a 12 V 7 A. Now, the Pi won't even start, no red LED or anything. Is it broken or is there a way to repair it? Even though I think it's dead, I'd like to know if there's a possible way to repair it.

Comment: The patient is dead. You have let the magic blue smoke escape.

Comment: Unfortunaly I think you're right..

Comment: Take it as a learning experience we ave all done it.

Comment: That's why it's nice they're so cheap! <$35

Comment: There is no economical way to repair a Pi.  There is an outside chance of survival if by 5V you mean the microUSB input as that has a polyfuse which may have tripped and may reset after a day or so.  If you mean a 5V pin on the expansion header there is no such protection.

Comment: Leave it un-powered for a couple of days and hope that the "PolyFuse" F1 might have saved it (it can take that long to reset) - but I am not optimistic.  Looks like you get the coveted (not) "rip" tag on this question... 8-/